# Trying to solve using recursion without using other algorithms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to get better at understanding recursion so that I can get better at implementing dynamic programming principles.  I am aware this problem can be solved using Kadane's algorithm; however, I would like to solve it using recursion.

Problem statement:

Given an array of integers, find the subset of non-adjacent elements with the maximum sum. Calculate the sum of that subset.

I have written the following partial solution:

```
const maxSubsetSum = (arr) => {
    let max = -Infinity

    const helper = (arr, len) => {
        if (len < 0) return max
        let pointer = len
        let sum = 0
        while (pointer >= 0) {
            sum += arr[pointer]
            pointer -= 2
        }
        return max = Math.max(sum, helper(arr, len - 1))
    }
    return helper(arr, arr.length - 1)
}
```

If I had this data:

```
console.log(maxSubsetSum([3, 5, -7, 8, 10])) //15 
//Our subsets are [3,-7,10], [3,8], [3,10], [5,8], [5,10] and [-7,10].
```

My algorithm calculates 13.  I know it's because when I start my algorithm my (n - 2) values are calculated, but I am not accounting for other subsets that are (n-3) or more that still validate the problem statement's condition.  I can't figure out the logic to account for the other values, please guide me on how I can accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

The code is combining recursion (the call to `helper` inside `helper`) with iteration (the `while` loop inside `helper`). You should only be using recursion.

For each element of the array, there are two choices:

1. Skip the current element. In this case, the sum is not changed, and the next element can be used. So the recursive call is
   `sum1 = helper(arr, len - 1, sum)`
2. Use the current element. In this case, the current element is added to the sum, and the next element must be skipped. So the recursive call is
   `sum2 = helper(arr, len - 2, sum + arr[len])`

So the code looks like something this:

```
const maxSubsetSum = (arr) => {

    const helper = (arr, len, sum) => {
        if (len < 0) return sum
        let sum1 = helper(arr, len - 1, sum)
        let sum2 = helper(arr, len - 2, sum + arr[len])
        return Math.max(sum1, sum2)
    }

    return helper(arr, arr.length - 1, 0)
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot, how would you memoize this solution?  Is it a 2D array or 1D array?

Comment: @Altaf I think it's a 1D array, since the only thing that needs to be memoized is the partial sum for a given `len`.

Comment: I am having trouble memoizing the solution, so what I did was declare an array before helper `const newArr = new Array(arr.length).fill(-1)` wrote a condition to return `if (newArr[len] !== -1) return newArr[len]` then changing the return for the helper function to `return newArr[len] = Math.max(sum1, sum2)`, but I am not doing something right.

Comment: This gives 0 for the input `[-3, -5, -7, -8, -10]`

Comment: @SomeDude Sure, the empty set is assumed to have sum 0, which is the best possible for that example.

Comment: @Altaf Yeah ...  I wasn't thinking about memoization when writing this code. The accumulation of the sum needs to be handled differently in order to make memoization work.

Comment: @user3386109 I see. Is it possible for you to show me how you would approach that?  My goal in this exercise was to be able to go from a recursive solution to implementing a memoized one, so that I can make the transition from recursive to dynamic programming.  I am weak at recursion, and a lot of the coding challenges I've encountered use dynamic programming which I find very difficult to implement.

Comment: @user3386109 what do you mean by empty set, is it because none of the elements could be combined with other to get an optimum sum? If that is the case, what should be result for [-3, -5, -7, -8, 10] here 10 cannot be combined with any other element to get optimum sum, should I consider empty set for this as well? Just thinking...

Comment: @SomeDude See the discussion between the two code snippets in the [Kadane's algorithm section of this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm).

Comment: @Altaf I think the best course of action is to start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is right in that you need to recurse from (n-2) once you start with a current index. But you don't seem to understand that you don't need to run through your array to get sum and then recurse.
So the right way is to

- either include the current item and recurse on the remaining n-2 items  or
- not include the current item and recurse on the remaining n-1 items

Lets look at those two choices:

Choice 1:

You chose to include the item at the current index. Then you recurse on the remaining n-2 items. So your maximum could be item itself without adding to any of remaining n-2 items or add to some items from n-2 items.
So *Math.max( arr[idx], arr[idx] + recurse(idx-2))* is the maximum for this choice. If *recurse(idx-2)* gives you -Infinity, you just consider the item at the current index.

Choice 2:

You didn't choose to include the item at the current index. So just recurse on the remaining n-1 items - *recurse(n-1)*

The final maximum is maximum from those two choices.

Code is :

```
const maxSubsetSum = (arr) => {
    let min = -Infinity
    const helper = (arr, idx) => {
      if ( idx < 0 ) return min
      let inc = helper(arr, idx-2)
      let notInc = helper(arr, idx-1)
      inc = inc == min ? arr[idx] : Math.max(arr[idx], arr[idx] + inc)
      return Math.max( inc, notInc )
    }
    return helper(arr, arr.length - 1)
}

console.log(maxSubsetSum([-3, -5, -7, -8, 10]))
console.log(maxSubsetSum([-3, -5, -7, -8, -10]))
console.log(maxSubsetSum([-3, 5, 7, -8, 10]))
console.log(maxSubsetSum([3, 5, 7, 8, 10]))
```

Output :

```
10
-3
17
20
```

- *For the case where all items are negative:*

In this case you can say that there are no items to combine together to get a maximum sum. If that is the requirement the result should be zero. In that case just return 0 by having 0 as the default result. Code in that case is :

```
const maxSubsetSum = (arr) => {
    const helper = (arr, idx) => {
      if ( idx < 0 ) return 0
      let inc = arr[idx] + helper(arr, idx-2)
      let notInc = helper(arr, idx-1)
      return Math.max( inc, notInc )
    }
    return helper(arr, arr.length - 1)
}
```

- *With memoization:*

You could memoize this solution for the indices you visited during recursion. There is only one state i.e. the index so your memo is one dimensional. Code with memo is :

```
const maxSubsetSum = (arr) => {
    let min = -Infinity
    let memo = new Array(arr.length).fill(min)
    const helper = (arr, idx) => {
      if ( idx < 0 ) return min
      if ( memo[idx] !== min) return memo[idx]
      let inc = helper(arr, idx-2)
      let notInc = helper(arr, idx-1)
      inc = inc == min ? arr[idx] : Math.max(arr[idx], arr[idx] + inc)
      memo[idx] = Math.max( inc, notInc )
      return memo[idx]
    }
    return helper(arr, arr.length - 1)
}
```

Comment: I like your solution as well, tried to memoize it like the solution above, but was not able to do it correctly, can you show how you would memoize the solution as well?

Comment: @Altaf I added with memo.

Comment: I tried your solution, it looks correct; however, I am getting a run time error for a lot of the test cases in this problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem , do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: @Altaf please consider any answer as a direction, you need to investigate further on your own for any other problems you may see.

Comment: Just trying to understand this line `inc = inc == min ? arr[idx] : Math.max(arr[idx], arr[idx] + inc)`  I know the purpose of this line is to compare the sum of the numbers at these indices, to see whether the sum is greater or if just the value at the index is greater, but I can't figure out how true condition satisfies this case.

Comment: In your second case I would expect the second case to be 0 because the sum of the empty set is always 0 and the empty set meets the condition.

Comment: @Altaf I didn't understand what you mean by *how true condition satisfies this case.*

Answer (score 1):

A basic version is simple enough with the obvious recursion.  We either include the current value in our sum or we don't.  If we do, we need to skip the next value, and then recur on the remaining values.  If we don't then we need to recur on all the values after the current one.  We choose the larger of these two results.  That translates almost directly to code:

```
    const maxSubsetSum = ([n, ...ns]) => 
      n == undefined  // empty array
        ? 0
        : Math .max (n + maxSubsetSum (ns .slice (1)), maxSubsetSum (ns))
```

**Update**

That was missing a case, where our highest sum is just the number itself.  That's fixed here (and in the snippets below)

```js
const maxSubsetSum = ([n, ...ns]) => 
  n == undefined  // empty array
    ? 0
    : Math .max (n, n + maxSubsetSum (ns .slice (1)), maxSubsetSum (ns))

console.log (maxSubsetSum ([3, 5, -7, 8, 10])) //15
```

But, as you note in your comments, we really might want to memoize this for performance reasons.  There are several ways we could choose to do this.  One option would be to turn the array we're testing in one invocation of our function into something we can use as a key in an `Object` or a `Map`.  It might look like this:

```js
const maxSubsetSum = (ns) => {
  const memo = {}
  const mss = ([n, ...ns]) => {
    const key = `${n},${ns.join(',')}`
    return n == undefined
      ?  0
    : key in memo
      ? memo [key]
    : memo [key] = Math .max (n, n + maxSubsetSum (ns .slice (1)), maxSubsetSum (ns))
  }
  return mss(ns)
}

console.log (maxSubsetSum ([3, 5, -7, 8, 10])) //15
```

We could also do this with a helper function that acted on the index and memoized using the index for a key.  It would be about the same level of complexity.

This is a bit ugly, however, and perhaps we can do better.

There's one issue with this sort of memoization: it only lasts for the current run.  It I'm going to memoize a function, I would rather it holds that cache for *any* calls for the same data.  That means memoization in the *definition* of the function.  I usually do this with a reusable external `memoize` helper, something like this:

```js
const memoize = (keyGen) => (fn) => {
  const cache = {}
  return (...args) => {
    const key = keyGen (...args)
    return cache[key] || (cache[key] = fn (...args))
  }
}

const maxSubsetSum = memoize (ns => ns .join (',')) (([n, ...ns]) => 
  n == undefined
    ? 0
    : Math .max (n, n + maxSubsetSum (ns .slice (1)), maxSubsetSum (ns)))

console.log (maxSubsetSum ([3, 5, -7, 8, 10])) //15
```

`memoize` takes a function that uses your arguments to generate a String key, and returns a function that accepts your function and returns a memoized version of it.  It runs by calling the key generation on your input, checks whether that key is in the cache.  If it is, we simply return it.  If not, we call your function, store the result under that key and return it.

For this version, the key generated is simply the string created by joining the array values with `','`.  There are probably other equally-good options.

Note that we *cannot* do

```js
const recursiveFunction = (...args) => /* some recursive body */
const memomizedFunction = memoize (someKeyGen) (recursiveFunction)
```

because the recursive calls in `memoizedFunction` would then be to the non-memoized `recursiveFunction`.  Instead, we always have to use it like this:

```js
const memomizedFunction = memoize (someKeyGen) ((...args) => /* some recursive body */)
```

But that's a small price to pay for the convenience of being able to simply wrap up the function definition with a key-generator to memoize a function.

Comment: Added a slight update based in comments from @גלעד ברקן.

Answer (score 0):

This code was accepted:

```js
function maxSubsetSum(A) {
  return A.reduce((_, x, i) =>
    A[i] = Math.max(A[i], A[i-1] | 0, A[i] + (A[i-2] | 0)));
}
```

But trying to recurse that far, (I tried submitting Scott Sauyet's [last memoised example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64246183/2034787)), I believe results in run-time errors since we potentially pass the recursion limit.

For fun, here's bottom-up that gets filled top-down :)

```js
function f(A, i=0){
  if (i > A.length - 3)
    return A[i] = Math.max(A[i] | 0, A[i+1] | 0);
    
  // Fill the table
  f(A, i + 1);

  return A[i] = Math.max(A[i], A[i] + A[i+2], A[i+1]);
}

var As = [
  [3, 7, 4, 6, 5], // 13
  [2, 1, 5, 8, 4], // 11
  [3, 5, -7, 8, 10] // 15
];

for (let A of As){
  console.log('' + A);
  console.log(f(A));
}
```

Comment: A nice approach, although I would much prefer to modify a `reduce` accumulator than our input list.  But that's a minor variant.  I looked for something like this, but missed one parameter to `max`: the current value by itself.  But do note that the question was specifically about how to do this recursively, starting "I am trying to get better at understanding recursion..."

Comment: @ScottSauyet that's why I offered my second method, which is recursive (and memoised).

Comment: @ScottSauyet I didn't notice that you forgot the case of the element on its own, I wonder if that's why some of the test cases failed with your code, rather than my assumption about recursion depth. But there seemed to be quite a few of them.

Comment: yeah, I didn't go to try it on that site.  I will probably fix up my answer now.  But I do like your approach, except that I really would prefer not to modify the input.

Comment: @ScottSauyet sure. If the input is needed, it wouldn't make sense to modify it.

Comment: That site doesn't accept even my fixed version.  Presumably it's a recursion-depth problem.  I could add a trampoline, but the only point of my answer was to show how to do this recursively, adding the memoization only because it was requested in comments to another answer.  I think your dynamic programming version is a cleaner way than this plain recursive one.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I would hope all of the information in the answers may be helpful to the OP.

Comment: No wonder this code would be accepted by the platform, but the OP specifically says : *Trying to solve using recursion without using other algorithms*

Comment: @SomeDude that's why I offered my second method, which is recursive (and memoised).